# Python Pandas: Looking for an efficient way to restructure this Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a Pandas Dataframe structured and populated as shown in the first Table, with date and number of sessions in each language.

I'd like to use this to populate a second dataframe (or restructure the first one) to be structured and populated as shown in the second table.

What is a clean elegant way to do this using Python Pandas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `df.pivot('SESSION_DATE', 'LANG',  'TOTAL_SESSIONS').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)`

Comment: fantastic! thank you